# Calculating potential energy in a molecular dynamics simulation

Tags: c

#### Background

Imagine that we have N particles inside a box of length L, which interact with each other (through a Lennard Jones potential).

I want to compute the total potential energy of the system. I implemented the function POT which calculates all the contributions from all the particles and gives the correct results (this is tested and can be assumed true).

I also wrote a function POT_ONE which only calculates the potential energy of one particle with respect to all the others. This means that if I want to calculate the total potential energy I will have to call this function N times (making sure that the particle does not interact with itself) and then divide by 2 since I double count the interactions.

#### Goal

My goal is to make the second function yield the same results as the first one.

#### Problem

There is something really strange going on: If I put 4 particles, the two functions give the same results. If I put a fifth one then there is deviation. Then for 6,7,8 particles,again, it gives correct results and then for N=9 I am getting a different result. In the case N=1000 the result that I am getting from POT_ONE is somemthing like 113383820348202024.

My results for N=5 are:
-0.003911 with POT and
12.864234 with POT_ONE

In case someone tries to run the code and wants to check the N=4 case, he/she should change the number of particles (np) which is defined as global variable and then comment the line `pos[12]=1;pos[13]=1;pos[14]=1;`.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*GENERAL PARAMETERS*/
int dim=3; //number of dimensions
int np=5; //number of particles
double L=36.413; //box length (A)
double invL=1/36.413; //inverse of box length

/*ARGON CHARACTERISTICS*/
double sig=3.4; // Angstroms (A)
double e=0.001; // eV


double distSQ(double array[]){
    /*calculates the squared distance given the array x=[dx,dy,dz]*/

    int i;
    double r2=0;
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++) r2+=array[i]*array[i];
    return r2;
}//distSQ

void MIC(double dr[],double L, int dim){
    /* MINIMUM IMAGE CONVENTION: dr[] is the array dr = [dx,dy,dz] describing relative
       positions of two particles, L is the box length, dim the number
       of dimensions */

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++) dr[i]-=round(dr[i]*invL)*L;
}//MIC

void POT(double x1[],double* potential){
    /*given the positions of each particle in the form x=[x0,y0,z0;x1,y1,z1;...;xn-1,yn-1,zn-1],
      the number of dimensions dim and particles np, it calculates the potential energy of the configuration*/

    //variables for potential calculation
    int i,j,k;
    double *x2;
    double r2inv; // 1/r^2
    double foo,bar;
    double dr[dim];
    *potential=0; // set potential energy to zero

    //main part of POT
    for(i=0;i<np-1;i++){
        x2=x1+dim;
        for(j=i+1;j<np;j++){
                //calculate relative distances between particles i & j
                //apply periodic BCs and then calculate squared distance
                //and the potential energy between them.
                for(k=0;k<dim;k++) dr[k] = x2[k]-x1[k];
                MIC(dr,L,dim); //periodic boundary conditions
                r2inv=1/distSQ(dr);
                //calculate potential energy
                foo = sig*sig*r2inv;
                bar = foo*foo*foo;
                *potential+=bar*(bar-1);

        }//for j
    x1+=dim;
    }//for i
    *potential*=4*e; //scale and give energy units
}//POT

void POT_ONE(int particle,double pos[],double* potential){

    *potential=0;
    int i,k;
    double dr[dim];
    double r2inv,foo,bar;
    double par_pos[dim];
    int index=particle*dim;
    par_pos[0]=pos[index];
    par_pos[1]=pos[index+1];
    par_pos[2]=pos[index+2];

    for(i=0;i<np;i++){
        if(i!=particle){
            for(k=0;k<dim;k++) dr[k]=pos[k]-par_pos[k];
            MIC(dr,L,dim);
            r2inv=1/distSQ(dr);
            foo=sig*sig*r2inv;
            bar=foo*foo*foo;
            *potential+=bar*(bar-1);
        }
        pos+=dim;
    }
    *potential*=4*e; //scale and give energy units
}//POT_ONE

int main(){

    int D=np*dim;
    double* pos=malloc(D*sizeof(double));
    double potential=0; //calculated with POT
    double U=0; ////calculated with POT_ONE
    double tempU=0;
    pos[0]=0;pos[1]=0;pos[2]=0;
    pos[3]=4;pos[4]=0;pos[5]=0;
    pos[6]=0;pos[7]=4;pos[8]=0;
    pos[9]=0;pos[10]=0;pos[11]=4;
    pos[12]=1;pos[13]=1;pos[14]=1;

    POT(pos,&potential);
    printf("POT: %f\n", potential);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<np;i++){
        POT_ONE(i,pos,&tempU);
        U+=tempU;
    }
    U=U/2;
    printf("POT_ONE: %f\n\n", U);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include example data, expected results, and the result you're getting. Thanks. Also, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [The Floating Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) may be helpful.

Comment: Great. Remember that titles help readers decide _now_ if they can help with your question, and it will help readers _in the future_ to decide if your question/answer post might help them with their problem. Titles should be both useful and succinct.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in `POT`, where you forgot to update `x2` at the end of the inner loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < np - 1; i++) {
    double *x2 = x1 + dim;

    for (j = i + 1; j < np; j++) {
        // ... calculate stuff ..

        x2 += dim;
    }

    x1 += dim;
}
```

An easier and arguably more readable variant is to forgo pointer arithmetic altogether and use boring old indices:

```
    for (k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
        dr[k] = x[j * dim + k] - x[i * dim + k];
    }
```

Further observations:

- Please make your variables local to the scope where they are used. A large list of uninitialized variables at the top of the function makes it very hard to track variables, even in a short function like yours.
- Please consider returning single values from functions instead of passing in pointers. In my opinion, that makes functions like the square of the distance more readable.
- The structure of your code is hard to see, because everything is run togeher very tightly, even the comments.

Comment: POT is running fine, it is tested with the same data with other implementation. Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: You calculate the potential by comparing all particles, right? `POT` does not do that, because it gets the coordinate references wrong. Implement the change I suggest and you will see that now both functions give the same result. (I've spot-tested this with randomized data for larger samples.) If you have reference data with correct answers, please share them in the post.

Comment: @FragiadoulakisAggelos, as presented in the question, `POT` does not behave the way the code comments within it claim it does.  Either the comments are incorrect or the code is.  The comments seem sensible, so my bet would be on it being the code that is wrong.

Comment: @MOehm Oh god you are right. This line was actually existing in my original function but I had to delete a few lines and this line was accidentally deleted as well.. Thanks man..